# Get data from one site collection into another site collection in same web application sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am using SharePoint 2016 on premise. I am having one web application in which i am having 2 site collections.
site 1 and site 2.
I want to show data from site collection 1 list on site collection 2 Page, using rest or java script or  J query. My environment is not configured with apps so i can't use apps and even server side code as well.
Please suggest any alternatives for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Share the script here in case someone have similar requirement.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        getDataFromSite1();
        getDataFromSite2();
    })

    function getDataFromSite1() {
        var url = "http://sp:12001/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items";
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }

    function getDataFromSite2() {
        var url = "http://sp:12001/sites/team/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items";
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Lee, Thanks for reply.
Actually i am having structure like below.
Site coll 1 :- http://AT2-004:33511
Site collection 2 :- http://companysitetwo.com (host header site collection).
So this code is not working for me on site collection 2.